# QtQuick: view allowing multiple selection at cell level

Tags: qml, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols

I'd like to implement a table view, using `QtQuick`, allowing multiple selection at cell level, emulating the behaviour of old style `QTableView` with `QAbstractItemView::SelectItems` and `QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection` flags enabled.

Which of the `QtQuick` components may I use?

Comment: Did you take a look at QML TableView http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#details ?

Comment: Of course! GridView page, in Qt docs, about GridView's selection: "This property contains the current row-selection of the TableView"

Comment: Seems like GridView allows only selection at rows level...

Answer (score 1):

[`TableView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html)only allow to select rows by default, but you can override the selection behavior by customizing its cell delegate ([`itemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#itemDelegate-prop)).

First you'll have to disable the default selection behavior with :

```
selectionMode: SelectionMode.NoSelection
```

Then in the [`itemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#itemDelegate-prop) you can do something like that :

```
        itemDelegate: Item {
            property bool isSelected: false

            // When user clicks on a cell, turn the isSelected flag on
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: isSelected = !isSelected
            }


            Text {
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

                // If this cell is selected, color the text in blue
                color: isSelected ? "blue" : "black"

                text: styleData.value
            }
        }
```

Be careful as the [signals emitted](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#activated-signal) by your [`TableView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html) will not work as your cells are accepting mouse events. But of course you can implement them easily if you need them.

Comment: Useful, thanks! Still missing a way to allow selection by mouse drag...

Comment: Should be possible if you define a [DropArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-droparea.html) on the cells